# android studio not including Kotlin JUnit tests written along with Java jUnit test

Tags: java, android, android-studio, junit, kotlin

I had a few JUnit tests written in Java. I have added new JUnit test classes which I have written in Kotlin. These classes are under the same folder where previously written JUnit Tests are located. i.e. `/test/java`.
When I run the JUnit tests, Android studio only runs JUnit tests which are written in Java. I can still run the JUnit classes written in Kotlin individually though.
I suspect this is happening when I upgraded my Android studio to 3.2 as it was running on Android Studio 3.1.

Comment: same here. It was working on AS 3.1 and now with AS 3.2 it runs only Java tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue is fixed in version 3.2.1 (https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/#3-2-0)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is an issue with Android Studio 3.2

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68021152#comment23

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17951